# Error while running migrate during Azure "web app + database" app setup

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm following this tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-dotnetcore-sqldb-app

I'm stuck at "4. Generate database schema", Step 2.2: In the SSH terminal:
"Run the migration bundle that's generated by the GitHub workflow with ./migrate".

At first, running that command generated error "Keyword 'port' is unknown".

I checked AZURE_MYSQL_CONNECTIONSTRING value that was auto-generated, it has the following format:

Server=xxx.mysql.database.azure.com;Database=xxx;Port=3306;User Id=xxx;Password=xxx;SSL Mode=Required

So I edited the port out, then I got the error "Keyword 'SSL Mode is unknown'", so I edited out ssl mode, now the string looks like this:

Server=xxx.mysql.database.azure.com;Database=xxx;User Id=xxx;Password=xxx

and I'm getting this error:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server: Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

in appsettings.json, I have:
"AZURE_MYSQL_CONNECTIONSTRING":"Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=MyDatabaseContext-ca7b86aa-xxx;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"

How do I make this work?

Comment: is the database `Azure SQL` or `MySQL` flexible server?

Comment: AFAIK your connection string is for `MySQL` server. and the code and steps are for `AzureSQL`.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue, thank you, azure bundle mentioned in the tutorial actually comes with a different server, so the code doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I followed this [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-dotnetcore-sqldb-app) to deploy an ASP.NET Core and Azure SQL Database app to Azure App Service.

- Install the following packages from the NuGet Gallery: `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools`.
- Code taken from [git](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/msdocs-app-service-sqldb-dotnetcore.git).

```cs
public class Todo
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Created Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

- Create an Azure Cache for Redis, Azure SQL database, Azure SQL server, and replace the Azure SQL Database connection strings in `appsettings.json`.

`Server=tcp:myserver.database.windows.net,1433;Database=myDataBase;User ID=mylogin@myserver;Password=myPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;`

- Open the package manager console to add a new migration to the project using Entity Framework.
  `Add-Migration YourMigrationName`.

[image]

- Updating a database with a migration in EF Core involves applying changes using the `Up` method from the [migration file](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/migrations/migration-files#up-method), or reverting changes using the `Down` method. To apply or undo a migration, run the `Update Command`.

`Update-Database`

[image]

- Add the Configuration Name `AZURE_SQL_CONNECTIONSTRING` with the Value [YourConnectionstrings](https://i.imgur.com/Hwrzboq.png) and  Name`AZURE_REDIS_CONNECTIONSTRING` with the Value [YourAzureCacheRedisConnectionString](https://i.imgur.com/uAJSIxl.png) in the Web [App](https://i.imgur.com/qcjtxkM.png).

[image]

- Add service [dependencies](https://i.imgur.com/P1SiNer.png) and publish the app to the Azure web app.

[image]

**Azure:**
[image]

- For [Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/flexible-server/overview) [MySQL](https://henriquesd.medium.com/deploying-a-net-6-web-api-and-a-mysql-database-with-azure-pipelines-decbe949a5d0), follow this [DOC](https://medium.com/@syedhassam2001/creating-and-deploying-net-7-minimal-api-and-mysql-database-on-azure-91f3f6828fb8).